# Standard horizontal scrollbar for specific div tag

Tags: html, css

I have one div tag, in which content goes outside of the pages width. I set the horizontal scrollbar for the div tag. The scrollbar is displayed at the bottom of the div, but I want the standard scroll bar of the browser to scroll the content of my div.

CSS:

```
.res_tbl {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="res_tbl" style="margin-top:40px;">
  <table class="tbl1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <!-- Table Heading Start -->
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div style="width:200px;" class="fix_height">
            <div class="sort_h th_1line">efafsdf</div>
            <div class="sort">
            <a class="sort_up" href="#"></a> 
            <a class="sort_dn" href="#"></a></div>
            <div class="eor"></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div style="width:200px;" class="fix_height">
            <div class="th_1line">sdfsfdsd</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div style="width:100px;" class="fix_height">
            <div class="sort_h th_1line">sfdsdfsfs</div>
            <div class="sort">
            <a class="sort_up" href="#"></a> 
            <a class="sort_dn" href="#"></a></div>
            <div class="eor"></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div style="width:110px;" class="fix_height">
            <div style="width:70px" class="sort_h">sfasfsdfs</div>
            <div class="sort">
            <a class="sort_up" href="#"></a> 
            <a class="sort_dn" href="#"></a></div>
            <div class="eor"></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div style="width:140px;" class="fix_height">
            <div style="width:85px" class="sort_h">sdfsafsfds</div>
            <div class="sort">
            <a class="sort_up" href="#"></a> 
            <a class="sort_dn" href="#"></a></div>
            <div class="eor"></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div style="width:140px;" class="fix_height">
            <div style="width:75px;" class="sort_h">asfsfsfsdfs</div>
            <div class="sort">
            <a class="sort_up" href="#"></a> 
            <a class="sort_dn" href="#"></a></div>
            <div class="eor"></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div style="width:140px;" class="fix_height">
            <div class="sort_h th_1line">sfsfsdfdsf</div>
            <div class="sort">
            <a class="sort_up" href="#"></a> 
            <a class="sort_dn" href="#"></a></div>
            <div class="eor"></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div style="width:140px;" class="fix_height">
            <div class="sort_h th_1line">sfsdffsdfsd</div>
            <div class="sort">
            <a class="sort_up" href="#"></a> 
            <a class="sort_dn" href="#"></a></div>
            <div class="eor"></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div style="width:100px;" class="fix_height">
            <div style="width:60px;" class="sort_h">safffsdfsafs</div>
            <div class="sort">
            <a class="sort_up" href="#"></a> 
            <a class="sort_dn" href="#"></a></div>
            <div class="eor"></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div style="width:100px;" class="fix_height">
            <div class="sort_h th_1line">sfdsdfsfsf</div>
            <div class="sort">
            <a class="sort_up" href="#"></a> 
            <a class="sort_dn" href="#"></a></div>
            <div class="eor"></div>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an automatic browser function, which you already mentioned. You created code that you didn't want. Just remove `overflow-x:scroll;` from your code.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HczcU/)